# What is the best practice to handle empty eloquent query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, null, eloquent

So far I'm using eloquent's `->exist()` and plain php's `isset()`...

Right now I'm using both of them..., when one doesn't work i'll switch to the other and then it will work.

But this makes the code looks dirty.. 
Do you have any suggestion when to use each of them, what's the difference.. what is the best practice for handling null eloquent query in laravel.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `empty()` method for this.

```
// After you initiate your model in variable
$var = Model::find($id);

// Just check it use empty method 
if(empty($var)) {
   // Do something here
}
```

**EDIT:**
Explanation of use native `exists()` and `isset()`in best practice.

As we know `isset` method is usually used to check if variable is defined or not.

```php
$col = "column"
if(isset($col)) {
   // true
}
if(isset($cols)) {
   // else
}
```

And for the usage `exists()`, usually it used to validate. You can check it in laravel documentation.

```php
$name = $request->get('name');
if(User::where('name', $name)->exists()){
  // It will true if the in users table exists the $name in name columns
  // And do something if true :D
} else {
  // If not exists/false you can return error like this

  return response()->json([
      'error'=>true
  ],400);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i would prefer an explanation of when to use the native eloquent ->exist() or php isset()...

Comment: Aaah okay-okay, look at my edited answer. I hope I can make it clear :D

Comment: You could also just use the count method `if ($var->count()){/*do something*/}` as if the model returns anything the count will be 1 and therefore eval as true.

Comment: Personally I would avoid using isset() for this kind of thing as it will return true if the var is set as null which is not what you want.

Comment: I usually use `empty` either use isset :D

Comment: I see... for now I'm using isset for query too lol, guess I'll use exist or empty instead. Thank you for answer!